# How to generate function definitions from ANTLR AST in java?

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have used Python3 grammar and have built an AST.
My source string is just a small function of Python.
My code is as follows:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "def sum( arg1, arg2 ):\r\n" 
                    + "   total = arg1 + arg2\r\n"
                    + "   print \"Inside the function : \", total\r\n"
                    + "   return total;\n";
    Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Python3BaseListener() {


        @Override
        public enterFuncdef(Python3Parser.FuncdefContext ctx) {
            //Here which function would give me the function definition?
        }
    }, parser.single_input());
}
}
```

Here, how do I output the name of the function? (sum)?
I am having a little hard time understanding the grammar.

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid `String` literal there? (and that it doesn't break Python's indentation)

Comment: Corrected the source string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. you should use the parser rule `file_input` as your starting point: `single_input` is used for [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)-like parsing of Python source
2. `public enterFuncdef` in not valid Java code: you're missing a return type (`void`, in this case)
3. the Python source you're parsing in not valid Python 3 source. `print "..."` should be `print("...")`

Now, if you look at the parser rule you're listening for:

```antlr
funcdef
 : DEF NAME parameters ( '->' test )? ':' suite
 ;
```

you see it has a `NAME` token. You can get a hold of it like this:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "def sum( arg1, arg2 ):\r\n"
            + "   total = arg1 + arg2\r\n"
            + "   print(\"Inside the function : \", total)\r\n"
            + "   return total;\n";

    Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Python3BaseListener() {
      @Override
      public void enterFuncdef(Python3Parser.FuncdefContext ctx) {
        System.out.printf("NAME=%s\n", ctx.NAME().getText());
      }
    }, parser.file_input());
  }
}
```

Running the class above will print: `NAME=sum`

Btw, there is an example from the grammar's repo that does exactly what you're trying to: https://github.com/bkiers/python3-parser/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/bigo/pythonparser/Main.java