# Create a Map of code & token from ANTLR generated parse tree in java

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using ANTLR for creating a parse tree for a python code using Java:

For the following python code:

```
def sum(a, b):

    return a + b

print("Hello World")
```

ANTLR outputs the following AST:

```
file_input
  funcdef
    parameters
      typedargslist
        tfpdef
        tfpdef
    suite
      simple_stmt
        return_stmt
          arith_expr
            atom
            atom
  atom_expr
    atom
    trailer
      atom
```

Is there a way in Java where I can map the type to the code as example:

```
funcdef : "def sum(a,b)"
parameters : "a,b"
simple_stmt : "return a + b"
```

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307503/how-to-generate-function-definitions-from-antlr-ast-in-java . Are you guys all doing the same class or something? I think you're the 3rd one asking about parsing Python3 code and extracting certain parse trees from it.

Comment: What ANTLR version? What does the grammar for your example look like? ANTLR v3's `CommonTree` has `startIndex` and `endIndex` attributes, which, if filled correctly by the grammar, point to first and last token. You can then get the original text from the input using this info.

Comment: Have used this grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You just navigate into the nodes of the ParseTree that you want and extract the text using [PaseTree.getText()](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTree.html)

It won't be directly on the nodes and child nodes are included with the parent in the tree so you'll need the specific terminal nodes.
The following code is just thematic, you'll have to toy with it to get what you want.

That said, you're better off using a implementing a [ParseTreeListener](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeListener.html) and responding as they occur rather then trying to navigate into parse tree explicitly.

```
Python3.FuncdefContext ctx = ...;

System.out.printf( "funcdef: def %s ( %s )\n", 
     ctx.getChild(1).getText() 
     ctx.getChild(2).getChild(0).getText()
     );
System.out.printf( "parameters: %s \n", 
     ctx.getChild(2).getChild(0).getText()
     );
System.out.printf( "simple_stmt: %s \n", 
     ctx.getChild(2).getChild(1).getText()
     );
```